# Break apart grid pattern of foams in mantaflow fluid sim

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

In Blender 2.82, mantaflow was introduced, with a built in way to generate foam, bubbles, and spray.

However, the particles all seem to be a bit too uniform, resulting in a grid like pattern.
[image: Grid like pattern example]

Is there a way to distort the pattern?

I am trying to get it to look something like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2EhrzmRQOE

or

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTfGo6tWkzE

Increasing the particle resolution just makes the grid tighter, and reducing the foam instanced sphere size makes the actual foam ridges less prominent (and you can still see the grid).

The sprays and bubbles also have this issue, though to a slightly lesser degree.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the issue is already tracked: https://developer.blender.org/T73552
Lets hope it gets fixed in the next release. I tried to break it up using a collection and different sizes of ico spheres but that doesn't work really well.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug in the official release, it has been fixed in the [daily builds](https://builder.blender.org/download/).

The first video you linked is actually done by me.